# Are you checking the tags when you read a question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, tagging

If you're voting to close, commenting on a question, or otherwise interacting with it, do you remember to check the tags? Improperly tagged questions won't badge hammer correctly, won't be viewed by people who would best be suited to answer the question, etc. This question is more of a PSA, something I've noticed over the past few months, and a bit of rhetorical question. Please take a moment to check the tags and fix them, especially if you are VTC a duplicate; this allows our badge hammer users to take appropriate action for obvious cases of duplicates.

Comment: Perhaps a clarification for those who don't have gold badges/dupe hammer: Gold badgers will lose their ability to dupe-hammer a question if they edit and add the relevant tag by themselves, so they depend on others to fix the tags.

Comment: One of the many ways in which this is helpful is defining the specialization, if applicable, for the question - helping surface it to the right users and allow others to pass it by. I use the presence of the `marketing-cloud` tag as a signpost that I probably don't have the expertise to evaluate a question, for example, but `email` alone doesn't help there. Conversely, I watch questions tagged `python` more closely.

Comment: I do check for the tag and infact many times I add appropriate tags .

Comment: I've noticed on a few occasions things like AMPscript questions being closed as off-topic. Clearly they're not, so I echo Brain's sentiment here!

Comment: Yup, Salesforce has become so broad that many things will appear OT if it isn't one's specialty or area of knowledge. Let a different person look at the question and they'll immediately recognize it as legit about a specific topic that we probably have a tag for. One that's often not tagged is `Identity` for many of those obscure questions, yet it broadly covers SSO, SAML, Idp, Ids, Named Credentials, Log-in Flows, Branding, Experience Id, and a whole lot more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been doing this for a long time by using **`Ignored Tags`** to monitor commonly abused tags such as `salesforce-community`, `salesforce1-app`, `help`, etc. I highly recommend trying to tag appropriately and definitely appreciate the shout out that we should all be paying attention to this feature of the Stack Exchange.